# Link Checker module not working properly

Tags: 7

I am using [Link Checker](https://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module to detect broken links. But the issue is its only showing those broken links that are going to a different domain.

For e.g my domain is www.xyz.com and if I used a link in body of a node like www.abc.com/sites/default/files/dummy_feb5.pdf.

In this case it it showing in broken link report but not displaying errors on same domain like www.xyz.com/sites/default/files/dummy_feb5.pdf.

What am I missing?

Comment: On the module page it states that it checks external links by default but not internal links. Perhaps you should enable this?

Comment: @undersound  I did all the configuration for internal links but still no internal link is dispalyed as en error in broken link report.

Comment: Could you provide some more info then? Screenshot of linkchecker settings? Do incorrect node url's show up?